# Submeter dados p/ base dados via SOCK_STREAM

Tags: c, socket

Olá, preciso de criar uma função que deverá fazer a ligação ao porto 80 do servidor "servername" proceder ao envio de um pedido em que a lista de parâmetros/valores do pedido POST é definida com base nos parâmetros dela.
Só que após a execução da função, o valor inserido nos parâmetros não está sendo inserido no formulário (PHP) do servidor, mesmo que estejam contidos no buffer.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_connect(char *servername, char *port);
void recv_server_reply(int s);
void submeter_dados(char *servername, char *uri, char *plate, char *owner, double value);

char http_msg[] = 
    "POST %sHTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: %s\r\n"
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
    "Content-Length: %ld\r\n"
    "Connection: close\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "%s";

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {

  //enviar dados
  submeter_dados("servidor.pt", "/ficheiro/redirecionado/peloformulario", "PL1819", "John", 5000.0);

  return 0;
}


void recv_server_reply(int s) 
{
  char buf[4096];

  printf("Reply from server: ");
  while(1) 
  {
    int n = read(s, buf, 1);
    if(n <= 0)
      break;
    putchar(buf[0]);
    fflush(stdout);
    if(buf[0]=='\n')
      printf(": ");
  }


  printf("\n\n");
}


int my_connect(char *servername, char *port) {

  //get server address using getaddrinfo
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *addrs;
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  int r = getaddrinfo(servername, port, &hints, &addrs);
  if (r != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(r));
    exit(1);
  }

  //create socket
  int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (s == -1) {
    perror("socket");  
    exit(2);
  }

  //connect to server
  r = connect(s, addrs->ai_addr, addrs->ai_addrlen);
  if (r == -1) {
    perror("connect");  
    close(s);
    exit(3);
  }

  return s;
}

void submeter_dados(char *servername, char *uri, char *plate, char *owner, double value){
    int sd = my_connect(severname, "80");

    char params[4096];
    char buffer[1000];
    sprintf(params, "plate=%.6s&owner=%s&value=%.2lf", plate, owner, value);
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), http_msg, uri, servername, strlen(params), params);

    write(sd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

    recv_server_reply(sd);
}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em http_msg, parece faltar um espaço entre o %s e o HTTP/1.1. Isto já é suficiente para o servidor não reconhecer a página que você está tentando acessar.

Consertando isso o exemplo parece funcionar e o servidor recebe os parâmetros (testei contra um servidor de teste feito em Express/Node.js).

Note também que você está usando a função write() de forma errada para sockets. Teria de fazer algo semelhante ao read(), ir chamando write() e analisar o valor de retorno, até escrever todo o conteúdo do buffer. Não é o que causa o seu problema no momento porque sua requisição tem poucos bytes e acaba sendo transmitida numa única chamada para write(), mas bastaria ela ser um pouco maior para quebrar de novo.